# Positiveness of Bilinear form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I would like to show that $$A = x^T G(x) \tanh(x) \geq 0$$ (with equality only for $x=0$), for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It is known that $G(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix.
Or come up with a counter-example if it does not hold.

I tried transforming to the associated quadratic forms $$A = \frac{1}{4}(x+\tanh(x))^T G(x) (x+\tanh(x)) -  \frac{1}{4}(x-\tanh(x))^T G(x) (x-\tanh(x))$$

I thought since $x$ and $\tanh(x)$ have the same sign, it should be obvious to conclude, but I might be missing something.
Is there a nice way to actually show it?

Comment: Is it assumed that $G(x)$ is positive definite? The wording is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, yes $G(x)$ is positive definite. I will rephrase.

Comment: $ \tanh(x)$ is not linear in $x\implies $ this is not a bilinear form.  Further this is a mapping $\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ not $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ which also means this is not a bilinear form.

Comment: Indeed, $y$ should be there instead of $tanh$, where x and y are constrained to have the same sign (component wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brainless computer search for counterexamples yields this one:

Take

$$G=\begin{pmatrix}6 & 3 & -1 \\ 3 & 10 & 3 \\ -1 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$x=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -10\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $x^T G \tanh x\simeq-1382$.

Comment: Oooops, it should. Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, thanks! 
It's just that G is assumed to be symmetric!  
I forgot to put it in the initial post (usually it is implied by the positive definiteness), I will edited it  :)

Comment: OK, how's this one?

Comment: Indeed, that works, although Matlab gives  -6.8478 instead of -1382 (still negative though). Thanks :)